# PHP - ob_start("ob_gzhandler") why the function not use directly in zend framework project?

Tags: php, zend-framework, buffer, ob-start

I beginer in zend framework.

ob_start("ob_gzhandler") - why the function not use directly  in zend framework project?

(does ob_start("ob_gzhandler") used auto in zend framework? )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Controller Response uses output buffering by default (you may disable it if you wish and use your own handler or oveload default response).

You may set up gzip compression in php.ini easily, so ob_gzhandler is not needed at all.